# HTML/CSS image follow height

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple design here, but i have a little issue.

Please have a look at the final design example here: http://ronnieaarebrot.com/demo/cms/

On the menu to the left and right, you can see a small border going from the top to the bottom (following the height of the center content).

How can i do this? i was planning on having a background-image with the small border on both sides, but how should i "calculate" the height of the center content? or make the two borders follow the height of the center div. This is a bit hard to explain.. but check the image and here is an html example of how far I've come. http://ronnieaarebrot.com/demo/cms_html/

Any good solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to contain the centre content in a div element and use the border CSS property to apply it. You can then adjust padding and margins to butt the centre and side elements against one another. Given the model, it seems like some padding on the centre element combined with almost no margins on the sides would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `overflow:hidden` on the `#page_wrap` element that it will extent to the height of its contents (*the left, center and right parts*).

So you can put the backgorund image (*1px height repeated vertically*) on that element and be sure that it will extend all the way down..